# Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.jvmargs Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.jvmargs

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle, classnotfoundexception

Whenever I try to run my flutter android app from main.dart it shows following error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.jvmargs
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.jvmargs
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1**

I have found different solutions but no one worked. Many solutions resolver error with gradle but in my case the main error is with class "org.gradle.jvmargs" and I found no direct solution related to it.

If I run android app from android studio of the same project by opening the android app feature of flutter in android studio then the apps works fine but directly from main.dart it doesnot works.